# How do I insert data from textbox to model in MVC?`

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

So I'm pretty new in MVC, I got Mission model:

```
public class Mission
{
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
    public string MissionType { get; set; }
    public string ElipseNumber { get; set; }
    public string MissionDate { get; set; }
    public string ReminderNumber { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

When the user is selecting a specific mission, it goes to the view as `@ViewBag.SelectedMission`

Now, I want to let the user have the option to add a note to a selected mission, so using a modal I added a textbox like so:

```
<div class="notesLabel">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Notes)
</div>
<div class="notesTextBox">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Notes)
</div>
```

Not sure exactly what to do, How do I take the input from the textbox and adding it to the SelectedMission.Notes?

Thanks from advance.

Comment: you can submit the form back to the action and get the values

Comment: @Usman: I have out one snippet below. Can you see if this is relevant,

Comment: @Unbreakable i have edited your answer to make it more clear to the op

Answer (score 0):

I am also a beginner but trying to help. From what I understand you can do something like below

**Contoller**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Mission model)
{
    var notes= model.Notes;
    //Set the values to view model accordingly and save to DB eventually
}
```

**View**

```
 @model Mission
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "ControllerName"))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        // ALL YOUR HTML FIELD WILL COME HERE 
        <div class="notesLabel">
           @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Notes)
        </div>
       <div class="notesTextBox">
           @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Notes)
       </div>
       <input type="submit" value="save">
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. The form will submit the details entered by user on button click. Assumption: the Controller name is `Home` and Action name which saves the notes data is `SaveNotes`. When user clicks the submit button, the data is sent to the `SaveNotes` action in `HomeController`. In action function, after validation is done, values are saved into to DB. If you don't want to save to DB, you can do anything as per your logic/design. Value will be in `objMission.Notes`.

```
<% Html.BeginForm("SaveNotes", "Home", FormMethod.Post); %>
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    :
    :
    <div class="notesLabel">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Notes)
    </div>
    <div class="notesTextBox">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Notes)
    </div>
    :
    :

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
<% Html.EndForm(); %>


public class HomeController : Controller  
{
    :
    :

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult SaveNotes(Mission objMission)
    {
        //Set the values to view model accordingly and save to DB eventually
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Missions.Add(objMission);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(objMission);
    }

    :
    :
}
```